# 2003 acrua mdx. Coolant leak between ac bracket and engine block dripping on corner of oil pan

Tags: coolant, leak, acura, mdx

This 2003 acrua mdx leaks coolant from the alternator and ac compressors bracket mounts and leaks between block down on the corner of the oil pan is there a freeze plug hole it could be leaking coolant from on the block or could it be the water pump sure could use some advice

Comment: Some photos would really help here.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you tell me which engine is in your MDX?

Comment: I doubt your engine uses freeze plugs when it's more likely one of three possibilities; blown head gasket, ruptured cooling system hose(s) or worn out water pump bearing. A blown head gasket would be obvious as coolant leaks out and enters cylinders to create major engine ruining problems. Presuming this isn't a blown head gasket leaves the other two possibilities.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This 2003  acrua  mdx dose not have steam coming out of the exhaust pipe so I don't think its the head oil is fine but they leak is where the the alternator and AC compressor is drips down on the corner of the oil pan will a water pump leak that far over thanks for your help